# how to insert multiple php array values into mysql for the same table?

Tags: php

Hi I am very new to php and I am having 3 php arrays namely bookname, bookprice and bookisbn, I need to insert the values like

`"bookisbn" "bookname" "bookprice"` into mysql

eg:

```
isbn1 bookname1 bookprice1 
isbn2  bookname2 bookprice2
isbn3  bookname3 bookprice3
```

As of now I tried to iterate the three arrays something like,

```
foreach($booknamearray as $bookname && $bookpricearray as $bookprice && $bookisbnarray as $bookisbn) { .. }
```

and

```
while($booknamearray as $bookname && $bookpricearray as $bookprice && $bookisbnarray as $bookisbn){ .. }
```

Nothing worked me, please kindly help me out to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,
Naveen.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they all have the same number of elements, you can use a for loop, and make a string of all the values:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($booknamearray); $i++) {
    $str = $booknamearray[$i] . " " . $bookpricearray[$i] . " " . $bookisbnarray[$i];
    //Insert $str into db
}
```

Comment: You are mixing js and php should be count($booknamearray) not $booknamearray.length

Comment: the joys of mixed language development :)

Comment: @General_Twyckenham: Its worked for me Thanks. Please Let me know if the length various, length will not vary in the above cases, but I may need to add the "bookofferprice" in the future. how to do in this case ?

Comment: Hey I think for the "bookofferprice" (various array length) below mentioned Marc B solution works I guess, Am I right ?

Comment: I think both Marc's solution and my solution will be able to handle adding bookofferprice, assuming the indices are the same. And yes, I did forget bookisbnarray[$i], good catch.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't say so explicitly, I'm guessing your 3 arrays have their various values in the SAME KEY, e.g.

```
$booknamearray[0] -> 'name1';
$bookisbnarray[0] -> 'isbn1';
$bookpricearray[0] -> 'price1';
```

In which case you can do

```
foreach($booknamearray as $key => $name) {
   $isbn = $bookisbnarray[$key];
   $price = $bookpricearray[$key];
   etc...
}
```